# ¿Cómo llamar una función con parametros, con addEventListener click?

Tags: javascript, funciones, eventos

```
const boton = document.getElementById("boton")

function saludo(nombre){
   document.write(`hola como estas ${nombre}`);
}
boton.addEventListener("click", saludo("alex"));
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tu pregunta necesita más detalles para aclarar el problema. Si crees que puedes agregar dichos detalles: explicación del problema o error, resultado esperado y comportamiento actual, puedes hacer clic en [edit]. De lo contrario mucho me temo que tu publicación termine cerrada. Saludos

Comment: Agrega descripcion referente a tu preguna, no solo pongas codigo

Answer (score 3):

De la forma en la que está definido, se está ejecutando directamente la función cuando se establece el *event listener*. En su lugar, puedes envolver con una *arrow function* para que se ejecute sólo cuando se capture el evento.

```js
const boton = document.getElementById("boton");

function saludo(nombre){
  document.write(`hola como estas ${nombre}`);
}

boton.addEventListener("click", () => saludo("alex"));
```

```html
<button id="boton">Click</button>
```